# Unable to update

Tags: command-line, updates, spotify

When I put in `sudo apt-get update` into the Command Line, I get the following:

```
E: Type 'new' is not known on line 67 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Before I saw this error line, I had tried installing Spotify according to the following (https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/), adding `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free` to my source.list (by going through the "Software & Updates" tab, "Other Software" and "add...". But then it replied, `Failed to load the package list`, giving the same account as above:

```
E:Type 'new' is not known on line 67 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list, E:The list of sources could not be read
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Thanks.

Comment: give us your sources.list file

Comment: It seems that the error tells you everything. Line 67 of `/etc/apt/sources.list` is funky so please [edit] to show us what it is and we can suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the file: /etc/apt/sources.list using text editor like gedit and remove the bad source in line 67 and save the file.

Then run the following command:

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Fixed -- indeed, there was a hangnail "new line of text" in the sources.list. Awesome. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The file which you have downloaded has some error with HTML code, this might be the reason for the error " The list of sources could not be read".

So remove the file or folder and try it with Trusted one.